# JNI directory structure c and java

Tags: java, c, class, java-native-interface, directory-structure

I've created 3 `JNI` classes and since I'm new to programming I just had them all in the same file but now I have to set up the directory for them in a professional sense.

This includes `src` for the source code and `bin` for the classes but I have no idea where to put the `.h` and `.so` files and how to compile everything so it works.

**I've tried** to look into classpaths and stuff but I seem to just be stuck and can't get my code to run properly. I'm **also trying** to understand and learn packages for this but I'm stuck on that too.

```
#spaces are just for easier reading atm

cd /home/pi/git/GPIO_I2C
mkdir bin
javac -d bin /home/pi/git/GPIO_I2C/src/com/company/gpioi2c/gpio/GPIOMethods.java -h ./bin

cd bin
gcc -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux -c "com_comapny_gpioi2c_gpio_GPIOMethods.h"

cd /home/pi/git/GPIO_I2C/src/c

gcc -o libmyGPIOMethods.so -shared -fPIC -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux GPIOMethods.c -lc 

sudo cp libmyGPIOMethods.so /usr/lib
cd /home/pi/git/GPIO_I2C/
java -cp /home/pi/git/GPIO_I2C/bin/com/company/gpioi2c/gpio GPIOMethods
```

This is **what I've tried** to compile so far for just one of the methods but I'm getting `Could not load main class` or `unsatisfied link error` depending on what I've changed?

Comment: Header files (`foo.h`) are needed only at compile time.  It is conventional to put them alongside the corresponding C source files, or occasionally in a separate `include/` directory, but as long as the C compilation is working correctly, whatever you are doing now is OK, in the sense that it is not a factor in whether the code runs correctly.

Comment: However, it is neither necessary nor useful to compile the header files themselves.  Instead, the JNI C source files should `#include` the appropriate header(s).

Comment: okay that makes sense, but what about the .so files. Do I need to put them somewhere special or how do I get them to be included?

Comment: But as for why you're getting the specific errors you're getting, it's hard to tell without more information.  Generally, we need to see a [mre] in order to answer questions about why your program isn't working correctly.

Comment: Alright I can try a hello world for this and post it

Comment: There is no need to `sudo cp` libraries around. You can get by with `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/pi/git/GPIO_I2C/src/c`

Comment: Even more, you can pass library location without altering `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` by using `-Djava.library.path=...`

Answer (score 0):

If you've managed to produce the .so file, what you need to do is tell the JVM where to find it. You do that by adding `-Djava.library.path=/directory/path/goes/here` to the JVM command line.

(Next step, make sure to call `System.loadLibrary("myGPIOMethods")` before you try to call any of your native methods).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-021/ where you can find sample of the code with various methods in different files.

You can also take a look here: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-021/

Basically, what you want to have is a structure where all the headers and C code are in one place while Java code is inside another place.

Basically, you can start with something as simple as:

```
.
|-- Makefile
|-- c
|   |-- recipeNo021_AnotherFunction.c
|   `-- recipeNo021_HelloWorld.c
|-- java
|   `-- recipeNo021
|       `-- HelloWorld.java
|-- lib
`-- target
```

When it comes to simple JNI code, start with something super simple: `Hello world!`

https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo001

Comment: dead links dead